# Tkinter windows fails to update after using OpenCV2 (facial recognition)

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm working on both Tkinter and OpenCV 2 (facial recognition). I'm making a program that when you press a single button (from Tkinter), the program start the recognition process, and when the user press "Escape" the recognition process stop and in the tkinter windows appears a new label indicating who the subject is.

This last thing isn't working. When I press "Escape", to finish the recognition process, the tkinter windows isn't updated with the new label.

The code is pretty large but here it is:

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
from Tkinter import *

global size
global fn_haar
global fn_dir
global Welcome

os.system("sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2")
size = 5
fn_haar = '/usr/share/opencv/haarcascade/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
fn_dir = '/home/pi/Control'

def recognition():
    (images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)
    subdir = "Subject 1"
    names[id] = subdir
    subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir)
    for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):
        f_name, f_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if(f_extension.lower() not in ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pgm']):
            continue
        path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
        lable = id
        images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
        lables.append(int(lable))
    (im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)
    (images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]
    model = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    model.train(images, lables)
    haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
    webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        rval = False
        while(not rval):
            (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
            if(not rval):
                print "Failed to open webcam. Trying again..."

        frame=cv2.flip(frame,1,0)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        mini = cv2.resize(gray, (int(gray.shape[1] / size), int(gray.shape[0] / size)))
        faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)

        for i in range(len(faces)):
            face_i = faces[i]
            (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
            face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))
            prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

            if prediction[1]<90:
                cv2.putText(frame,'%s - %.0f' %(names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),(x-10, y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))

            else:
                cv2.putText(frame,'Unknown',(x-10, y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))

        cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
        cv2.moveWindow('OpenCV', 350, 120)
        key = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if key == 27:
            cv2.startWindowThread()
            cv2.destroyWindow('OpenCV')
            L1 = Label(Welcome, text = "The subject is:" + names[prediction[0]]).pack()

Welcome = Tk()
Welcome.title ("Welcome")
Welcome.geometry ("300x100+1+1")
LabelWelcome = Label(Welcome, text = "Welcome to the facial recognitio program").pack()
B1 = Button(Welcome, text="START", command=recognition).pack()
Welcome.mainloop()
```

The program runs fine until I press "Escape", and then it doesn't update the windows with the new label and the windows just freezes.

So, after doing some tests I think the problem is that "cv2.destroyWindow('OpenCV')" destroy the mainloop or something like that.

My questions are:

- Is that the problem ? cv2.destroyWindow('OpenCV') destroy the mainloop too?
- If that is the problem, what can I do about that?
- If thats not the problem do you know what can be?

PD: I'm thinking that maybe, if the problem is with cv2.destroyWindow, I can just hide that windows (openCV) and not close it (don't know if this is possible).
PD2: I know that if this code works, I'm going to add a label every time I run the recognition part, but I'm ok with that for the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"The program runs fine until I press "Escape", and then it doesn't update the windows with the new label and the windows just freezes."_ -->  That is usually a while statement that never exits.

Comment: _when the user press "Escape" the recognition process stop_  --> Where do you bind the Escape to an action?

Comment: With key = cv2.waitKey(10) and  "if key == 27:" I can bind the escape key to an action. And maybe you are right, the recognition program is in a while True loop. I'm going to test tomorrow if changing that works. Thanks!